# How best to assemble a large collection of message handlers

Tags: .net, inversion-of-control

I am starting work on a message processing system, where a variety of messages will arrive from an external source and need to be "handled". The message objects are basically DTO's.

I am thinking of having the message classes live in their own assembly, available both to the message processing system and to the external system, and having the handlers inherit from a generic abstract class, along the following rough lines:

*Messages.dll*

```
public abstract class Message {}

public class FooMessage : Message
{
  ...
}

public class BarMessage : Message
{
  ...
}
```

*MessageHandlers.dll*

```
public abstract class MessageHandler<TMessage> where TMessage : Message
{
  public void Handle(TMessage message);
}

public class FooHandler : MessageHandler<FooMessage>
{
  public void Handle(FooMessage message)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

**And now the question**:
What is the best way to glue all this together? I can certainly do a bit of reflection and write a helper function to instantiate the appropriate handler based on the incoming message name, but isn't this exactly the sort of thing IoC containers are supposed to be good at? Is there a particular one better suited for the job? Opinions and pointers appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be surprised if .NET's IObservable doesn't already have something that does this, but I'm not super familiar with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to register your handlers. I always start by configuring everything by hand. In your example, it would look like this:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
container.Register<IMessageHandler<FooMessage>, FooHandler>();
container.Register<IMessageHandler<BarMessage>, BarHandler>();
// etc
```

***Tip**: Rather than using a abstract base class, define an `IMessageHandler<T>` interface.*

Once the application is growing, this can get cumbersome, so in your case, batch registration should be the way to go. All DI containers have different mechanisms for this. Most containers support this out of the box, while others don't. Here is how to do it using [Simple Injector](http://simpleinjector.net):

```
<!-- language: c# -->
container.RegisterManyOpenGeneric(typeof(MessageHandler<>),
    typeof(MessageHandler<>).Assembly);
```

This will register all concrete types that implement `MessageHandler<T>` and live in the same assembly as the `MessageHandler<T>`. Again, it depends on your container of choice how to write this.

For processing incoming arbitrary messages, you will need a bit of reflection, but you shouldn't do this in the application itself. Just define a good abstraction in the application and move the use of reflection inside the part of the application where you have your DI configuration.

What you can do for instance, is define an `IMessageProcessor` interface, that allows processing any type of `Message`:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
public interface IMessageProcessor
{
    void Process(Message message);
}
```

Near your DI configuration, you can define an implementation of `IMessageProcessor`, and it could look like this:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
private class DIMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor
{
    private readonly Container container;

    public DIMessageProcessor(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public void Process(Message message)
    {
        if (message == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("message");

        Type messageType = message.GetType();

        Type handlerType =
            typeof(IMessageHandler<>).MakeGenericType(messageType);

        var handler = this.container.GetInstance(handlerType);

        handlerType.GetMethod("Handle").Invoke(handler, message);
    }
}
```

Leaving this out of the application is important. Not only would you be mixing responsibilities, but it would be harder to add new behavior. Think for instance about preventing message replays (when a message is executed multiple times). It would be easy to implement this behavior as a decorator of `IMessageProcessor`. Besides this, the `DIMessageProcessor` would be easy to unit test, or replaced with a new more performant implementation (and unit tested again).

There are several ways to register the `DIMessageProcessor`, depending on your container of choice. Using Simple Injector for instance:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
container.RegisterSingle<IMessageProcessor>(new DIMessageProcessor(container));
```

With this in place you can inject the `IMessageProcessor` into the types that need this. Here is an example for WCF:

```
<!-- language: c# -->
[ServiceKnownType("GetKnownMessageTypes")]
public class WCFMessageService
{
    private readonly IMessageProcessor processor;

    public WCFMessageService()
    {
        this.processor = 
            Global.Container.GetInstance<IMessageProcessor>();
    }

    [OperationContract]
    public void Process(Message message)
    {
        this.processor.Process(message);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetKnownMessageTypes(
        ICustomAttributeProvider provider)
    {
        var knownMessageTypes =
            from type in typeof(Message).Assembly.GetTypes()
            where typeof(Message).IsAssignableFrom(type)
            select type;

        return knownMessageTypes.ToArray();
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar based on Windsor a while back. You can read about this [here](http://kozmic.pl/2010/03/11/advanced-castle-windsor-ndash-generic-typed-factories-auto-release-and-more/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all components are correctly configured in the container, this is how you can handle a message (where the message in this case is a serialized message being transported over a queue):

```
var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (var s = new MemoryStream(message.AsBytes))
{
    dynamic consumable = formatter.Deserialize(s);

    var consumerType = typeof(IMessageConsumer<>).MakeGenericType(consumable.GetType());
    dynamic consumer = this.container.Resolve(consumerType);
    consumer.Consume(consumable);
}
```

Full sample code is available here: https://github.com/ploeh/CQRSonAzureDemo/blob/master/BookingWorkerRole/AzureQueueMessageProcessor.cs

Comment: @Mark, thank you, could you also point me to where the container is configured in this app?

Comment: The background worker container is configured here: https://github.com/ploeh/CQRSonAzureDemo/blob/master/BookingWorkerRole/WorkerRole.cs

Comment: @Mark, so really this, right: https://github.com/ploeh/CQRSonAzureDemo/blob/master/BookingWorkerRole/DomainModelWindsorInstaller.cs ? Does that mean that each handler would have to be configured individually? I was hoping for a bit less friction.

Comment: That's a different concern. In that app I never got around to define convention-based configuration, but that would be possible.

Comment: @Mark, its one of my main concerns -- the question is about the best way to glue this together (so both registration and resolution).

Comment: There's lots of information about how to enable convention-based registration. Here's an example regarding Castle Windsor: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627027/castle-windsor-using-convention-registration-along-with-specific-implementations

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to use a Request/Response messaging pattern you can use the [Agatha (agatha-rrsl)](http://github.com/davybrion/Agatha) project.
It is an implementation of that pattern, it is mature, tested under heavy load and [works in-process](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/12/running-an-agatha-service-layer-in-process-without-wcf/) and of course outside the process boundaries using WCF.

It has built-in everything you mention and integrates with many popular IoC containers (Windsor, StructureMap, Unity, Spring.NET, Ninject) so you will not have to re-invent the wheel and start focusing on your business logic.

You may find very useful articles, usage tips, and a lot of information on Davy Brion's blog [here](http://davybrion.com/blog/category/agatha/).

Comment: thank you, but Agatha is not what I am after. Its the wrong type of communication pattern for my use case. Here's the relevant config part though: https://github.com/davybrion/Agatha/blob/master/Agatha.ServiceLayer/ServiceLayerConfiguration.cs

Comment: @Michael, what is the pattern you describe? I read about DTOs, messages and message handlers. Yes this part you mention is for using agatha with wcf.