# Castle Windsor (IOC) Basics

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I am new to Castle Windsor and am trying to grok the basics...

I have the following code...

```
namespace WindowsBash.Models
{
    public interface IShouter
    {
        string Display();
    }

    public class Shout : IShouter
    {
        private IMessage _message;

        public Shout(IMessage message)
        {
            _message = message;
        }        

        public string Display()
        {
            return _message.TheMessage();
        }
    }

    public interface IMessage
    {
        string TheMessage();
    }

    public class MessageHello : IMessage
    {
        public string TheMessage()
        {
            return "Hello";
        }
    }

    public class MessageBye : IMessage
    {
        public string TheMessage()
        {
            return "Bye";
        }
    }
}
```

I then have the following method to try and test what Windsor is doing....

```
private void TestIOC()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(
        AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<IShouter>()
                .Where(x => x.Namespace.StartsWith("WindowsBash"))
                .WithService.AllInterfaces());

    var MyShouter = container.Resolve<IShouter>();
    var result = MyShouter.Display();
}
```

Right now this always returns "Hello". If I wanted it to return "Bye", what would I need to change without changing the order of the classes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use auto-wiring.  If not, you can do manual registration for each of your components. (Edit: looks like you discovered one-by-one registration on your own :) ).

See the chosen answer for this question to use auto-wiring but control the default implementation for a specific type:

[Castle Windsor: Using convention registration along with specific implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4627027/castle-windsor-using-convention-registration-along-with-specific-implementations)

Comment: Thanks, this helped the most. I can see that the benefit of auto wiring is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this that seemed to work...

> ```
>     private void TestIOC()
>     {
>         var container = BootstrapContainer();
>         container.Register(
>             Component.For<IShouter>().ImplementedBy<Shout>(),
>             Component.For<IMessage>().ImplementedBy<MessageBye>());
>
>         var shell = container.Resolve<IShouter>();
>         var result = shell.Display();
>
>         container.Dispose();
>     }
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Windsor 3:

```
private void TestIOC()
{
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(
        AllTypes.FromAssemblyContaining<IShouter>()
                .Where(x => x.Namespace.StartsWith("WindowsBash"))
                .WithService.AllInterfaces()
                .ConfigureFor<MessageBye>(c => c.IsDefault()));

    var MyShouter = container.Resolve<IShouter>();
    var result = MyShouter.Display();
}
```

However usually if you only want one component out of several, just don't install the other ones - put in the container only what you want for that particular context.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this done in XML so you can configure it outside of compiled classes:

http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v21/usersguide/externalconfig.html

Comment: Thanks, but I am wanting to do it in code by adjusting the TestIOC method.

Answer (score 0):

You could either register them with a name, or ResolveAll and find the correct one. However, what you want to do is not really useful in real life, because when registering multiple implementations, you probably want to use all implementations.